# only create a object of a nest inner class inside a member function

Tags: java, inner-classes

Suppose I have an inner class B that I will create an instance of inside one of the member functions of outer class, is there a way that I can do it without creating a instance of outer class?

Thanks a lot.

```
class A {
    class B {

    }

    public void function() {
       // create an instance of B, normally have to create a 
       // instance of A to be bond to by b
       B b = new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: B taken as a static in A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you do this is by declaring `B` `static`:

```
class A {
    static class B {
```

This means that `B` does not have an instance of `A` associated with it, and can be instantiated in contexts where no outer instance of available.

That said, your current code compiles fine as-is (since `function()` is non-`static`, there *is* an instance of `A` available in this context).

Answer (score 1):

you can create object of `class B` from outside of `class A` like

> B b = new A().new B();

But here you are creating instance of outer class then creating instance of inner class.  It is not possible inner Object creation without creating a instance of outer class.

But it is possible if your inner class is `static` then you could do it.

```
class A {
    static class B {

    }
}
class C{
   public void test(){
       B b = new B();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an instance of outer class if you are accessing the nested/inner class within the method of outer class.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create an instance of `class B` inside member function of `class A`. In fact `class B` is like a member(variable/function of A) if `Class A`. It can be accessed directly like other members. So there is no problem in

```
 public void function() {
   // create an instance of B, normally have to create a 
   // instance of A to be bond to by b
   B b = new B();
 }
```

If you want to create instance of `class B` outside the scope of `class A`, then only you need the instance of `class A` to create instance of `class` B like this

```
A a = new A();
B b = a.new B();
```

Suppose you want to create instance of `class B` outside the scope of `class A` without instance of `class A`, then declare `class B` as static which means `class B` does not bounded inside the scope of `class A`

```
class A {
    static class B { 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```